# Uniqueness in the Snake Lemma.

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

There is something which really bothers me. In all the references I looked (including the internet), no one talks about the uniqueness of the connecting morphism constructed in the Snake Lemma. The only source I found is this (beautiful) website :
[Uniqueness of the connecting morphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491307/uniqueness-of-the-connecting-homomorphism-in-theory-of-abelian-categories)
where it is made clear that we do not have the strict uniqueness.

My question is then : Is the connecting morphism $\delta : Ker \ c \rightarrow Coker \ a$ unique up to isomorphism ? I'm working with abelian categories, so I would appreciate a "purely" categorical argument.

Comment: [I'm just going to leave this here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etbcKWEKnvg)

Comment: You can find a "purely categorical" proof (by which I mean a proof without diagram chasing, although this is perfectly valid in abelian categories as well) in [Categories and Sheaves](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kashiwara2.pdf) at page 297. There the connecting morphism is constructed via universal properties, which immediately implies uniqueness.

Comment: What do you mean by unique up to isomorphism ? Of course, if you have a fix diagram, the snake lemma says that we have an isomorphism $\operatorname{coker}(\ker b\to\ker c)\simeq \ker(\operatorname{coker}a\to\operatorname{coker}b)$, if there is one, there usually plenty of them... As an example, you can always take $-\delta$. Now, the snake lemma produces a canonical one (and natural).

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491307/ you linked yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is in finding the property with respect to which the connecting morphism should be unique. A complete and purely categorical answer is given in [this result](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/010H) in the Stacks Project.